# retriving html form data with flask python even if not all input fields are filled

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        price1 = int(request.form.get('price1'))
        price2 = int(request.form.get('price2'))
        price3 = int(request.form.get('price3'))
        price4 = int(request.form.get('price4'))
        price5 = int(request.form.get('price5'))

        quantity1 = int(request.form.get('quantity1'))
        quantity2 = int(request.form.get('quantity2'))
        quantity3 = int(request.form.get('quantity3'))
        quantity4 = int(request.form.get('quantity4'))
        quantity5 = int(request.form.get('quantity5'))
        global total_change_price
        total_change_price = price5/price1

        price_list.extend([price1, price2, price3, price4, price5])
        quantity_list.extend([quantity1, quantity2, quantity3, quantity4, quantity5])

        # make calculations with the following lists
        global corr
        corr = correlation(price_list, quantity_list)

        # user submiting a file
        file = request.form.get("file")

        print(file)
        return redirect(url_for("view_data"))
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

What can I do in the case if not all input fields in the form are filled, in this example it gives me this error TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType', since the user is only inputing the file and not the price1, price2 and other input fields. thanks in advance!

I am giving the user the option to either type the info for price1, price2...until quantity5, but also to submit just the file and leave the above empty.

Comment: If the user leaves a price blank, what do you **want** to happen?  Do you want the code to use a default value (perhaps 0) for any price that is missing?

Comment: No, in that case I read the prices I read from excel :)

Answer (score 1):

When querying the values of the form, you can specify both a default value and a function for type conversion.

The following example returns 0 if no value is specified or the conversion to int fails.

```py
price1 = request.form.get('price1', 0, type=int)
```